# DataGridView - "Cell Selection Style" - Edit Cell

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on a WinForm client with a DataGridView control. I notice users have to click once to select the cell and again to edit it. What is the way to change this to a single click edit mode? I thought I had seen something like this before but can't remember the name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I have noticed a problem with `EditMode.EditOnEnter`
It biases a lot of DataGriView's default behavior, which is irritating. 
Among others, the edited cell stays in edited mode even when the EndEdit method is explicitly called (you are force to click on another control to make the datagridview cell lose its focus.)

The following piece of code works pretty fine as it makes you edit by single clicking on any cell and ending the edit by hitting enter or clicking outside the DGView (just as you would do in the default behavior)

Here you go :

```
    private void myDatagridView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            hitTestInfo = myDatagridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell) 
                myDatagridView.BeginEdit(true);
            else 
                myDatagridView.EndEdit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 24):

In the DataGridView properties: **EditMode -> EditOnEnter**

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a 'Click and Hold' to edit the cells: dataGridView_List is the name of my DataGridView

DataGridView EditMode Property is set to EditProgrammatically

Create a class to key track of cell and a timer (with a hold time - say 500milliseconds) and then use CellMouseDown/Up events to start/stop timer

```
   public class cellEdit
    {
        int Row;
        int Col;
        readonly int elapsedtime;
        readonly Stopwatch SW;
        public cellEdit(int iElapsedTimeInMillisecons)
        {
            elapsedtime = iElapsedTimeInMillisecons;
            SW = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }
        public void Start(int iRow, int iCol)
        {
            {
                Row = iRow;
                Col = iCol;
                SW.Restart();
            }
        }
        public bool Stop(int iRow, int iCol)
        {
            SW.Stop();
            if (iRow == Row && iCol == Col) if (SW.ElapsedMilliseconds > elapsedtime) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

in Form

```
    public cellEdit GetCellEdit = new GetCellEdit(500);  // 500mS
```

add datagridview CellMouseUp and CellMouseDown events

```
    private void dataGridView_List_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > 0 && e.RowIndex < dataGridView_List.Rows.Count && e.ColumnIndex > 0 && e.ColumnIndex < dataGridView_List.Columns.Count)
            GetCellEdit.Start(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
    }
    private void dataGridView_List_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > 0 && e.RowIndex < dataGridView_List.Rows.Count && e.ColumnIndex > 0 && e.ColumnIndex < dataGridView_List.Columns.Count)
            if (GetCellEdit.Stop(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex))
            {
                dataGridView_List.CurrentCell = dataGridView_List.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                dataGridView_List.BeginEdit(false);
            }
    }
```

Now cell goes into edit mode if you click and hold the mouse for 1/2 second