# DataGridViewButtonCell requires two clicks to trigger event

Tags: c#, button, datagridview

I have created a form that comprises mainly of a dataGridView, the far right column is a DataGridViewButtonColumn, and I am handling the event in the CellContentClicked handler.

My issue is that when the buttons in the column are clicked once, no events are triggered however, for each row, if the button is clicked once then once again, the CellContentClicked event is triggered. For example, if the user goes through the whole list of rows and clicks each button once, no event is triggered, however if they then went back and clicked any one of the already clicked buttons the event fires.

Any ideas why the dataGridView is waiting for a second click? Is it waiting for some kinf of focus?

Thanks!

Edit: I have tried to apply the solutions provided in the post: [DataGridView - "Cell Selection Style" - Edit Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379409/datagridview-cell-selection-style-edit-cell) however they were not successful in solving my issue :(

Handler code is as follows:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;// Cast sender to DataGridView type

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)// check column is button column
    {

        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Style.BackColor == SystemColors.Window)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
            {
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
            {
                cell.Style.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView - "Cell Selection Style" - Edit Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379409/datagridview-cell-selection-style-edit-cell)

Comment: Try changing the EditMode property to EditOnEnter.

Comment: You would have to post code that duplicates the problem.  The EditOnEnter should have resolved the issue.

Comment: I am unfortunately unsure from where the error is coming so cannot provide code to replicate the bug, could this be an issue with Visual Studio?

Comment: No, Visual Studio is not the problem.  What error?  Create a new project and put a DataGridView control on it and try to recreate your problem that way.

Comment: What is the color of the cells when you first click on the button row?  Are you inspecting the values when you debug the routine?

Comment: The DefaultCellStyle BackColor property is set to 'Window', I even tried a method to run through the dataGridView at startup and set each cell to that colour

Comment: I don't think the color of the cell is what you think it is.

Comment: But when I implicitly set the colour of a row to, say violet, and then check for that colour in the click event, two clicks are still required. The first click clears the colour back to white however

Comment: Is EditOnMode set to EditOnEnter?  I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176887/discussion-between-jake-doe-and-larstech).

Comment: `The first click clears the colour back to white however`  Then it worked.

Comment: I would reverse your logic.  Switch SystemColors.Window with Color.AliceBlue and vice-versa.  DGV does weird things with that Style class sometimes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I think you're right though that seems the best course of action. Will post a solution if found. Thanks, Lars